# Google Map API v3 and Joomla Mootools Conflict

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, joomla, mootools

I have upgraded to Google Map API v3 today and started to get mootool-core.js error. Please have a look at my site and code below. Any help would be appreciated.

[Website Link](http://turnierpferde.de/anzeigenmarkt/10-pferde/springpferde/3227-top-junioren-lehrpferd,-m-mehrfach-platziert.html)

[Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12lRc.png)

```
  <script>
        function initMap() {
            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                zoom: 11,

            });

            geocodeAddress(geocoder, map);

        }

        function geocodeAddress(geocoder, resultsMap) {
            var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
            geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function (results, status) {
                if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    resultsMap.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        map: resultsMap,
                        position: results[0].geometry.location
                    });
                } else {
                    alert('Address not found: ' + status);
                }
            });
        }

    </script>
```

Comment: what's your console log error?

Comment: Console log error is - GET http://turnierpferde.de/anzeigenmarkt.raw?view=map&city=Horb&postcode=72160…schland&title=TOP%20Junioren-%20/%20Lehrpferd,%20M*%20mehrfach%20platziert 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: it's server error.not mootools or Gmap api error!

Comment: this seems to work now - close pls.